# How do you prevent glitching when trying to render something in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

So, I'm trying to make a character move across the screen using arrow keys, and while it works, it leaves streaks. I don't want streaks coming out my back end. I know why it is making those streaks, but don't know how to get rid of them. The cause of the streaks is that the player is getting cleared from the canvas, then with a BIG delay, it renders. How do I stop that?

Edit: I want it to ONLY clear the player, and nothing around it.

Snippet:

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = c.getContext('2d')

c.height = window.innerHeight
c.width = window.innerWidth

let blockInfo = {
    h: 15, // Height in pixels. I'm gonna use this like blocks, like this: blockAmount * blockInfo.h
    w: 15
}

let renderedPlayer = false // The player wasn't rendered yet so this is false

let player = {
    speed: 0.125,
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    height: 1,
    width: 1
}

function clearPlayer() { // I think this is where the glitch comes in.
    ctx.clearRect(player.x * blockInfo.w, player.y * blockInfo.h, player.width * blockInfo.w, player.height * blockInfo.h)
}

function renderPlayer() {
    ctx.fillRect(player.x * blockInfo.w, player.y * blockInfo.h, player.width * blockInfo.w, player.height * blockInfo.h)
}

function press(e) { // When a character on the keyboard gets pressed:
    let w = e.which
    
    if (renderedPlayer == true) {
        clearPlayer() // It clears the player before the player moves, so it doesn't have more streaks.
        
        if (w == 39) {
            player.x += player.speed
        } else if (w == 37) {
            player.x -= player.speed
        } else if (w == 38) {
            player.y -= player.speed
        } else if (w == 40) {
            player.y += player.speed
        }
    }
}

setInterval(function() { // Rendering player each MS.
    renderedPlayer = false
    renderPlayer()
    renderedPlayer = true
}, 0)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body onkeydown="press(event)">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clear the whole canvas at start of every frame. It gets really hard to clear just the moving object when you start to have many of them. `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)` is very very fast. Also use `requestAnimartionFrame` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame rather than walking memory leak that is `setInterval`

Comment: That would help, but you could've said this as an answer and not a comment. But still, thank you for teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just clear the entire canvas before you draw, like this:

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = c.getContext('2d')
c.height = c.width = 180

let blockInfo = {h: 15,  w: 15}
let player = {speed: 0.1, x: 2, y: 2, height: 1, width: 1}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
  
  //renderOtherStuff
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.arc(75, 75, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);  
  ctx.fill();

  //renderPlayer
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x * blockInfo.w, player.y * blockInfo.h, player.width * blockInfo.w, player.height * blockInfo.h)
}

function press(e) { // When a character on the keyboard gets pressed:
  let w = e.which
  if (w == 39) {
    player.x += player.speed
  } else if (w == 37) {
    player.x -= player.speed
  } else if (w == 38) {
    player.y -= player.speed
  } else if (w == 40) {
    player.y += player.speed
  }
}

setInterval(render, 25)
```

```html
<body onkeydown="press(event)">
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
```

Clearing just the player presents other problems as you introduce other objects that might overlap, as you clear the player you also clear the background that could contain something else.

...Also, this looks like the start of a simple game, if you are serious about it, look into a proper gaming engine, there a bunch of Open Source ones:
https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: Sorry, but I did mention that I didn't want it to clear anything, but the player. Why I only want it to clear the player is because if I add a different thing in the canvas, it would get cleared also. You can edit this answer if you have a solution to that.

Comment: @UnknownBobby this same solution applies when you are drawing multiple things, you should clear the entire canvas and draw everything again

Comment: @UnknownBobby I edited my answer to show how it looks with a different thing in the canvas ... but when you have time do look into a proper gaming engine that will save you a lot of headaches later

Comment: Yes, but I don't like copying. It makes me feel.. I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean you don't like copying? Do you think you can create a better game engine all by yourself? and using a game engine you will not be copying, you will be using a good set of tools to build your game. _ _ _ think of if like a carpenter, you can use a hand saw to build something or a professional electric saw table that will give you fast and accurate cuts every time

Comment: I mean, I feel bad. I just don't like copying. Nothing really important, but if I have to copy to learn or be successful, I'll copy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226259/discussion-between-unknown-bobby-and-helder-sepulveda).